# Adding more fields or linking user to person

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello I'm trying to learn django and django-restful-framework.

I was wondering can I add more fields to User(contrib.auth) like so

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'email',
                  'phone', 'jobTitle','image', 'isActive','groups')
```

This gives me error on firstName. I also tried to tie this with person, but no luck either

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('url', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'ssn', 'owner')



class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    persons = serializers.ManyHyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='person-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'persons')
```

I'm trying to make this so that the user can register with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you head to the [Django docs on extending and/or replacing the existing user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Once you've got what you want as the model level see if you can serialize that to your needs. (If not post again.)

Answer (score 1):

The field names are lowercase with underscores. E.g it should be `first_name` and not `firstName`.